# Is it possible to make bootable USB for Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, live-usb

I own an Akoya P2212T (Intel Celeron N2920, FHD Touchscreen with USB port) and have tried booting Ubuntu Desktop and it works.

Now I would like to try out Ubuntu Touch on this device. But, how do I make a bootable USB from the daily images of Trusty (tar/zip)? As far as I can see, instructions are only available to flash android-based tablets. Is it possible to make bootable USB for Ubuntu Touch?

Comment: Why are we closing this? There's nothing off-topic about it.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu Touch system isn'ẗ designed for PCs yet. Currently, it supports phones and tablets. Hopefully, some time this year, it'll get support for a desktop interface as well. I'd imagine some time after that, we'll get images for PCs.

Of course, Ubuntu Desktop currently supports touch screens, if that's what you're after.